# Number of divisors of a product

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be the number of divisors of two positive integers , is it possible to explicitly express the number of divisors of their product only in terms of $a$ and $b$? If not , how can it be calculated efficiently without actually calculating the product?

Comment: The number-of-divisors function $\sigma_0$ is multiplicative, which means $\sigma_0(nm)=\sigma_0(n)\sigma_0(m)$ if $n,m$ are coprime. The number $\sigma_0(nm)$ is not *generally* determined by that of $\sigma_0(n)$ and $\sigma_0(m)$ though.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of divisors function be $d$. Then, it is known that $$ d(mn) = d(m) \cdot d(n), $$ for $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1$. That is, $d$ is multiplicative for relatively prime inputs. But not in general.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.You just can't express it in terms of a and b.

I'm telling you a general method through an example.

Let Numbers is 20.

$20 = 2^25^1$
Number of divisors = (2+1)(1 + 1) = 6

So number of divisors of $a_1^{p_1}a_2^{p_2}...a_n^{p_n} = (p_1 + 1)(p_2+1)...(p_n+1)$
where $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are prime numbers.

These are total number of divisors (including 1 and the number itself).

Comment: Very nice, but if the logic were there too, then would be great for beginners like m to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b$ are coprime, yes and the answer is $ab.$ In general, I don't think there is such expression.

Consider the $(12,4)$ case :

$12=2^2\cdot 3^1$ has $(2+1)(1+1)=6$ divisors, and $4=2^2$ has $2+1=3$ divisors.

On the other hand, $12\cdot 4=48=2^4\cdot 3^1$ has $(4+1)(1+1)=10$ divisors.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then the number of divisors of $ab$ is the product of the number of divisors of $a$ and the number of divisors of $b$.  If they are not, then the relationship could be a lot more subtle.

You'd be better off using the explicit formula for the number of divisors in the general case.  If $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then $d(n) = (a_1+1)(a_2+2)\cdots (a_k+1)$.  Finding the number of divisors of a product of two numbers, if they aren't relatively prime, involves looking at this formula to figure out which factors need to change and how, for any primes that divide both.